# Elastic Subtraction aggregation on two date fields

Tags: date, go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am not so familiar with elastic search aggregation. So I am not sure how to figure out this.

I need to create a consolidation page for an e-commerce platforme where, for each order I Need to calculate some fields ( date type ). based on other fields.

For example field A : Click to Ship = field b - field c ( both b and c are dates ).

By reading the docs, I think that I need to implement scripted fields but I am not 100% sure.

I am using go and github.com/olivere/elastic/v7 as an elastic lib.

Any idea on how to do this ?